# How can, "It still doesn't work" be rephrased as a question?

Tags: grammar, questions

How could the statement, "It still doesn't work” be converted to a question?

I want to ask if something is still out of order or not.

Comment: "Work'nt?" (i'm joking.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Does it still not work?

Alternatives are:

> Is it still not working?
>
> Is it still out of order?
>
> Is it fixed yet?

Comment: How about replacing "not working" with "broken" or "busted"? Not as formal, but probably more common.